# Partition a set of factors so that the difference between products is minimized

Tags: algorithms, knapsack-problems, primes, factoring

I'm sure this problem must be well-known...

Given a collection $S$ of numbers, partition them into exactly two sub-collections, $A$ and $B$ (I mean, by definition $B$ is just $S-A$) such that the difference of *products*
$$
    \Delta = \left|\left(\prod_{x\in B}x\right) - \left(\prod_{x\in A}x\right)\right|
$$
is as small as possible.

If it helps, you can assume that all the members of $S$ are integers, and in fact you can assume that they are all prime! In [my particular use-case](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/10/18/oeis-a125508/), we're trying to split some big integer $n$ into its "squarest possible" pair of factors, and $S$ is simply a prime factorization of $n$ which we happen to have lying around.

What's the best way to do this? The brutish ways I have thought of are:

- Trial division (assuming everything is prime). Awful performance.

```
    int PS = productOf(S);
    for (int PA = sqrt(PS); PA >= 1; --PA) {
        if (PS % PA == 0) {
            int PB = PS / PA;
            return { factorsOf(PA), factorsOf(PB) };
        }
    }
```

- Search all the possible partitions. Would give better performance, I think, because $\lvert S\rvert! \ll \prod{S}$, but still "obviously" a dumb algorithm.

```
    int currentDiff = productOf(S);
    intset currentA = {};
    for (intset A in partitionsOf(S)) {
        int PA = productOf(A);
        int PB = productOf(S)/PA;
        if (PB >= PA && PB-PA < currentDiff) {
            currentA = A;
            currentDiff = PB-PA;
        }
    }
    return { currentA, S - currentA };
```

Is there any simple-ish algorithm to solve this problem without relying on brute exhaustive search?

I wonder if it would work to minimize the difference of *sums* $\sum_{x\in B}{\log{x}} - \sum_{x\in A}{\log{x}}$, and if that problem has a simpler known solution...

Comment: A quick note regarding your final point on minimising the difference of logs: the problem can be reduced to 2-partition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is NP-complete, but has a pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming solution (efficient in practice).

Comment: Here is relevant link to the problem you want to solve: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/subset-sum-vs-subset-product-strong-vs-weak-np-hardness/16913#16913

Comment: FWIW, that problem seems like "split S so that $\prod{A} = \prod{B}$ exactly," and I don't (yet) understand how to adjust the solution to merely _minimize_ the difference $\prod{B}-\prod{A}$.

Comment: Are you looking for practical solutions or do you care about theoretical running time?  If practical, what are the typical sizes of the sets and the numbers?

Comment: @D.W.: I'm looking for practical solutions IRL, but I'm also morbidly curious about impractical ones and would not downvote them. My inputs are the-prime-factorizations-of consecutive integers starting at $n=2$, so my set sizes are [$\Omega(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function) for whatever that's worth. :) Circa $n=10^9$, my "trial division" algorithm becomes noticeably "slow." I have not yet implemented the "search all partitions" algorithm because I decided I'd better ask for better algorithms before I spend the time to implement another one.

Comment: @Quuxplusone H'm, you're right. For $\Sigma A-\Sigma B$ the standard reduction from the exact case to the minimisation problem is to check if there's an exact solution, then to check if there's an exact solution when you add $x=1$ to the set, then replace it with $x=2$, etc. I'm not sure such tricks will work for $\Pi$.

Comment: For the products you’d to check for an exact solution you’d factor into primes, every prime must occur an even number of times, and then you have to divide all primes simultaneously into two equal sets. I suppose that will be NP-complete but will work very quick in many practical cases. If the numbers are so large that factoring is hard, then you only need to know if they have common divisors.